# remove an entry from HashMap depending on the Enum type of the value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to create a json from an Object. The Object contains a List member variable of type Name. Name is a class which contains an enum NameType. below are the class:

```
public final class Person { private final List<Name> names; }

public class Name {

    private final String first;

    private final String last;

    private final String middle;

    private final NameType type;
}
public enum NameType {
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

The json that is produced for class Person should not include Name for which NameType is Y and Z. Below is the simple way in which I try to generate the json:

```
 Map<String, Object> personMap = mapper.readValue(person!=null ? mapper.writeValueAsString(person) : "{}", typeReference);
```

I need to remove the key "names" from personMap. I have searched a few ways to remove it before serialization, but that hasn't worked for me. I followed this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization
and tried to remove it using type and using filter, but because this is an enum so didn't work for me. So, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to not include the Name property as part of serialization based on NameType.
2. If there is any way to remove after serialization is done.
   Below is the structure that is generated for the map.[image]

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Perhaps @JsonIgnore could be used?

Comment: Your Question seems to roam all over the place. Is the question about filtering a `Map`? Or is the question about serializing to JSON? I suggest a re-write, without any extraneous distractions.

Comment: @BasilBourque, I disagree. The question is quite clear in what it wants to achieve. At least I understand it. Only the way the OP tried to do it is inadequate,  because the linked tutorial is about avoiding to serialise a whole property, which in this case he wants to avoid serialising objects based on property values, which is not the same. Not serialising `Person.names` does not help, because it is a list which contains some objects he wants and others he does not want. Something like a `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` does not do what he wants. `@JsonIgnore` does not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I never used Jackson before, this was my first contact. I was just looking for a little puzzle to solve while drinking my morning tea, which also enables me to learn something. So I am not sure if there are better or more elegant ways of doing this.*

In order to present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which everyone can easily compile and execute, here are my more complete versions (including getters) of your example classes:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71358052;

public enum NameType {
  REAL,
  ARTIST,
  ONLINE
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71358052;

public class Name {
  private final String first;
  private final String last;
  private final String middle;
  private final NameType type;

  public Name(String first, String last, String middle, NameType type) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    this.middle = middle;
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getFirst() {
    return first;
  }

  public String getLast() {
    return last;
  }

  public String getMiddle() {
    return middle;
  }

  public NameType getType() {
    return type;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71358052;

import java.util.List;

public final class Person {
  private final List<Name> names;

  public Person(List<Name> names) {
    this.names = names;
  }

  public List<Name> getNames() {
    return names;
  }
}
```

As described for a similar case in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria#2-custom-serializer), we can use a custom `JsonSerializer<Name>` in combination with a `BeanSerializerModifier`, registering them on the `ObjectMapper` in a `SimpleModule`:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71358052;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;

public class NameSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Name> {
  private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;

  public NameSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> serializer) {
    defaultSerializer = serializer;
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Name value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    if (value.getType() != NameType.REAL)
      return;
    defaultSerializer.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, Name value) {
    return value == null || value.getType() != NameType.REAL;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71358052;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;

import java.util.List;

public class JacksonDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Person person = new Person(List.of(
      new Name("Edward", "Robinson", "G.", NameType.ARTIST),
      new Name("Emanuel", "Goldenberg", null, NameType.REAL),
      new Name("Эмануэль", "Голденберг", null, NameType.REAL),
      new Name("Eddie", "The Gangster", null, NameType.ONLINE)
    ));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
    String personJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);

    System.out.println(personJson.contains("ARTIST"));      // false
    System.out.println(personJson.contains("ONLINE"));      // false
    System.out.println(personJson.contains("Goldenberg"));  // true
    System.out.println(personJson.contains("Голденберг"));  // true
    System.out.println(personJson);
  }

  private static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    objectMapper.registerModule(
      new SimpleModule() {
        @Override
        public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
          super.setupModule(context);
          context.addBeanSerializerModifier(
            new BeanSerializerModifier() {
              @Override
              public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                if (Name.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass()))
                  return new NameSerializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
                return serializer;
              }
            }
          );
        }
      }
    );
    return objectMapper;
  }
}
```

The console log should be:

```
false
false
true
true
{"names":[{"first":"Emanuel","last":"Goldenberg","type":"REAL"},{"first":"Эмануэль","last":"Голденберг","type":"REAL"}]}
```

Oh, by the way and just in case not everybody knows who [Edward G. Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_G._Robinson) was...